# How can I combine odd and even numbered lines?

Tags: text

I want to combine every even-numbered line with the line above it. Something like:

```
Line one,csv,csv,csv
Line two,csv,csv
Line three,csv,csv,csv,csv
Line four,csv
```

The result should look like this:

```
Line one,csv,csv,csv,Line two,csv,csv
Line three,csv,csv,csv,csv,Line four,csv
```

Any ideas how to achieve that in either Perl or sed/awk?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perl's builtin variable [$.](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#%24.) will tell you the line number. `$. % 2` will be `1` if `$.` is odd, and `0` otherwise. Here is a self-contained example;

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict; use warnings;

my $buffer;

while (my $line = <DATA>) {
    if ($. % 2) {
        chomp $line;
        $buffer = $line;
    }
    else {
        print join(",", $buffer, $line);
    }
}

__DATA__
Line one,csv,csv,csv
Line two,csv,csv
Line three,csv,csv,csv,csv
Line four,csv
```

Output:

```
C:\Temp> tt
Line one,csv,csv,csv,Line two,csv,csv
Line three,csv,csv,csv,csv,Line four,csv
```

Answer (score 20):

here it is, with sed:

```
sed '$!N;s/\n/,/'
```

and with awk:

```
awk '{if (e) {print p","$0;} else {p=$0;} e=!e;}'
```

or

```
awk 'NR%2==0 {print p","$0;} NR%2 {p=$0;}'
```

Comment: Even shorter than `perl -pe '$|--||s!$/!,!'`!

Comment: @mob, `$. % 2 &&` is just as short as `$|-- ||` yet much less special.

Comment: I love that sed option, and it is _wicked_ fast. Can someone please explain what the "$!" at the start of the sequence does? 'N;s/\n/,/' seems to get almost the same result.

Comment: @PieterMüller there is no need for `$!` at the start of the sequence as seds `N` or `n` commands  will terminate any further commands if they try to read beyond the end of the file. However it will still print the pattern space if the `-n` option is not set.

Comment: Does not work on ubuntu. Just concatenates the characters from the second line which start from position where first line ends.

Answer (score 12):

This is what the `paste` command is for. Assume your output is generated with `command`, then you can do:

```
$ command | paste -d, - -
```

or if the output is stored in a file

```
$ paste -d, - - <file.csv
```

Example:

```
paste -d, - - <<END
Line one,csv,csv,csv
Line two,csv,csv
Line three,csv,csv,csv,csv
Line four,csv
END
```

outputs:

```
Line one,csv,csv,csv,Line two,csv,csv
Line three,csv,csv,csv,csv,Line four,csv
```

Comment: Haven't heard of paste, and it's not clear to me what `process_to_produce_output` should be for this problem. More details?

Comment: A (Solaris) man page for paste is [here](http://bama.ua.edu/cgi-bin/man-cgi?paste). The question itself does not say how the input is produced. Is it a file or the output from some other process?

Comment: Thanks much for the link, my Cygwin man page was far less helpful.

Comment: On cygwin, `info paste` will give you a tutorial.

Comment: `paste` merges lines of files together, with a default TAB delimiter. If you specify `-` as a file, it interprets that as STDIN. So `paste -d, - -` means: merge lines from STDIN and STDIN, using `,` as a delimiter instead of TAB. If you use `paste -d, - - -`, it will join every 3 lines together, `- - - -` will be every 4 lines, and so on.

Comment: **note:** older comments reference older edits of this answer

Comment: It would be nice if it could be explained why the double hyphen behaves as it does. `paste file file` behaves differently then `paste - - <file`

Comment: @kvantour, Linus's comment does that.

Comment: @glennjackman true, but only partly. But I think what I'm after is the internals only. I'm wondering now if similar behaviour is with other tools too. `cat` behaves identically. So I think it is a stream or filehandle feature.

Comment: I would think it's up to the implementation of each individual tool. You could check the source code for the definitive answer.

Comment: Does not work on ubuntu. Just concatenates the characters from the second line which start from position where first line ends

Comment: @abb, I don't understand your comment. Can you provide an example?

Comment: For input -                         <input type="hidden" class="endDate" value="2021-03-03T19:00:00Z" />
                            <span class="inline-element spots-remaining">0</span>

Comment: I get output as - ,                            <span class="inline-element spots-remaining">0</span>00:00Z" />
,                            <span class="inline-element spots-remaining">0</span>00:00Z" />

Comment: Your input file uses `\r\n` line endings. You'll need to remove the carriage returns. Use `dos2unix` or `sed -i 's/\r$//' file`

Answer (score 3):

And another one:

```
awk -F, ORS=NR%2\?FS:RS infile
```

You don't need to quote the ? with most *shells*.

Comment: This is amazing!

Answer (score 2):

Generally, you'd accumulate data in a buffer until you have enough to know what to output, then you output the data.

```
my @buf;
while (<>) {
    chomp;
    if (!@buf) {
       push @buf, $_;
       next;
    }

    my $line1 = shift(@buf);
    my $line2 = $_;
    print("$line1,$line2\n");
}
```

But in this case, there exists a much simpler solution since your problem can be restated to be: Replace every second newline with a comma, starting with the first.

```
perl -pe's/\n/,/ if $. % 2' file
```

Answer (score 1):

A slightly simpler Perl solution.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

while (<DATA>) {
  chomp;
  print "$_," . <DATA>;
}

__DATA__
Line one,csv,csv,csv
Line two,csv,csv
Line three,csv,csv,csv,csv
Line four,csv
```

Answer (score 0):

you don't need those nuclear weapons like perl/sed/awk to solve this problem. 
`xargs` is enough.

```
xargs -d '\n' -n2
```

**test**

```
kent$  echo "Line one,csv,csv,csv
Line two,csv,csv
Line three,csv,csv,csv,csv
Line four,csv"|xargs -d '\n' -n2
Line one,csv,csv,csv Line two,csv,csv
Line three,csv,csv,csv,csv Line four,csv
```

Comment: Well, if you don't care about the missing _FS_ between the trailing _cvs_ and _Line_ :)

Comment: xargs -n2 ('\n' is the default value for the -d option) works all the same, seems easy to remember. A nice trick to add to my collection. Thanks