# Trailers option in git --pretty option

Tags: linux, git, awk, grep

I was trying to extract a summary of contributions from git log and create a concise summary of that and create an excel/csv out of it to present reports.

I did try

```
git log --after="2020-12-10" --pretty=format:'"%h","%an","%ae","%aD","%s","(trailers:key="Reviewed By")"'
```

and the CSV looks like with a blank CSV column at the end.

```
...
"7c87963cc","XYZ","xyz@abc.com","Tue Dec 8 17:40:13 2020 +0000","[TTI] Add support for target hook in compiler.", ""
...
```

and the `git log` looks something like

```
commit 7c87963cc
Author: XYZ <xyz@abc.com>
Date:   Tue Dec 8 17:40:13 2020 +0000

    [TTI] Add support for target hook in compiler.

    This adds some code in the TabeleGen ...
    This is my body of commit.

    Reviewed By: Sushant

    Differential Revision: https://codereviews.com/DD8822
```

What I couldn't be successful was in extracting the `Differential Revision` string using the `(trailers:key="Reviewed By")` command.

I couldn't find much on how to get this working.
I checked the git manual and I did try what it explains.

Is there something I might be missing in this command?
The expected output should have the text
`https://codereviews.com/DD8822` at the last position in the above CVS output.

Comment: Could you please explain more on Logic part of getting sample output, along with sample output in your question; to make question more clear.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 done.

Comment: one thing I notice is your `trailers` placeholder doesn't have `%` at the beginning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure but:

- trailer keys cannot have whitespaces (therefore `Reviewed By` -> `Reviewed-By`, and `Differential Revision` -> `Differential-Revision`);
- trailers should not be delimited by new lines, but separated from the commit commit message (therefore `Reviewed By` from your question is not considered as a trailer).

I would also not recommend using CSV, but using TSV instead: git output is not aware of CSV syntax (semi-colons and commas escaping), therefore the output document may be generated unparsable.

If your commit messages would look like this (`-` instead of spaces, no new line delimiters):

```
commit 7c87963cc
Author: XYZ <xyz@abc.com>
Date:   Tue Dec 8 17:40:13 2020 +0000

    [TTI] Add support for target hook in compiler.

    This adds some code in the TabeleGen ...
    This is my body of commit.

    Reviewed-By: Sushant
    Differential-Revision: https://codereviews.com/DD8822
```

Then the following command would work for you:

```sh
git log --pretty=format:'%h%x09%an%x09%ae%x09%aD%x09%s%x09%(trailers:key=Reviewed-By,separator=%x20,valueonly)%x09%(trailers:key=Differential-Revision,separator=%x20,valueonly)'
```

producing short commit id, author name, author email, date, commit message, trailer `Reviewed-By`, and trailer `Differential-Revision` to your tab-separated values output.

---

If you may not change the old commit messages because your history is not safe for doing this (it's published, pulled by peers, your tools are bound to the published commit hashes), then you have to process the `git log` output with `sed`, `awk`, `perl`, or any other text-transforming tool to generate your report. Say, process something like `git log --pretty=format:'%x02%h%x1F%an%x1F%ae%x1F%aD%x1F%s%x1F%n%B'` where lines between `^B` (STX) and EOF should be analyzed somehow (filtered for the trailers you are interestged in), then joined to their group lines starting with `^B`, and then character replaced to replace field and entry separators with `\t` and no character respectively.

But again, if you may edit the history by fixing commit message trailers (not sure how much it may affect), I'd recommend you do that and then reject the idea of extra scripts processing trailers that are not recognized by `git-interpret-trailers` and simply fix the commit messages.

---

#### Edit 1 (text tools)

If rewriting the history is not an option, then implementing some scripts may help you out. I'm pretty weak at writing powerful `sed`/`awk`/`perl` scripts, but let me try.

```sh
git log --pretty=format:'%x02%h%x1F%an%x1F%ae%x1F%aD%x1F%s%x1F%n%B' \
    | gawk -f trailers.awk \
    | sed '$!N;s/\n/\x1F/' \
    | sed 's/[\x02\x1E]//g' \
    | sed 's/\x1F/\x09/g'
```

How it works:

- `git` generates a log made of data delimited with standard [C0 C1 codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C0_and_C1_control_codes) assuming there are no such characters your commit messages (STX, RS and US -- I don't really know if it a good place to use them like that and if I apply them semantically correct);
- `gawk` filters the log output trying to parse STX-started groups and extract the trailers, generating "two-rowed" output (each odd line for regular data, each even line for comma-joined trailer values even for missing trailers);
- `sed` joins odd and even lines by pairs (credits go to [Karoly Horvath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7841607/how-can-i-combine-odd-and-even-numbered-lines/7841752#7841752));
- `sed` removes STX and RS;
- `sed` replaces US to TAB.

Here is the `trailers.awk` (again I'm not an `awk` guy and have no idea how idiomatic the following script it, but it seems to work):

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f

BEGIN {
    FIRST = 1
    delete TRAILERS
}

function print_joined_array(array) {
    if ( !length(array) ) {
        return
    }
    for ( i in array ) {
        if ( i > 0 ) {
            printf(",")
        }
        printf("%s", array[i])
    }
    printf("\x1F")
}

function print_trailers() {
    if ( FIRST ) {
        FIRST = 0
        return
    }
    print_joined_array(TRAILERS["Reviewed By"])
    print_joined_array(TRAILERS["Differential Revision"])
    print ""
}

/^\x02/ {
    print_trailers()
    print $0
    delete TRAILERS
}

match($0, /^([-_ A-Za-z0-9]+):\s+(.*)\s*/, M) {
    TRAILERS[M[1]][length(TRAILERS[M[1]])] = M[2]
}

END {
    print_trailers()
}
```

A couple of words how the `awk` script works:

- it assumes that records that do not require processing are starting with STX;
- it tries to `grep` each non-"STX" line for a `Key Name: Value` pattern and saves the found result to a temporary array `TRAILERS` (that serves actually as a multimap, like `Map<String, List<String>>` in Java) for each record;
- each record is written as is, but trailers are written either before detecting a new record or at EOF.

#### Edit 2 (better `awk`)

Well, I'm really weak at `awk`, so once I read more about `awk` internal variables, I figured out the `awk` script can be reimplemented entirely and produce a ready to use TSV-like output itself without any post-processing with `sed` or `perl`. So the shorter and improved version of the script is:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

git log --pretty=format:'%x1E%h%x1F%an%x1F%ae%x1F%aD%x1F%s%x1F%B%x1E' \
    | gawk -f trailers.awk
```

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f

BEGIN {
    RS = "\x1E"
    FS = "\x1F"
    OFS = "\x09"
}

function extract(array, trailer_key, __buffer) {
    for ( i in array ) {
        if ( index(array[i], trailer_key) > 0 ) {
            if ( length(__buffer) > 0 ) {
                __buffer = __buffer ","
            }
            __buffer = __buffer substr(array[i], length(trailer_key))
        }
    }
    return __buffer
}

NF > 1 {
    split($6, array, "\n")
    print $1, $2, $3, $4, $5, extract(array, "Reviewed By: "), extract(array, "Differential Revision: ")
}
```

Much more concise, easier to read, understand and maintain.

Comment: Also worth mentioning: there is a bunch of work going on in Git right now to beef up the trailer handling. I don't think this allows spaces but I'm not sure as I have not been paying attention to it.

Comment: Thanks for detailed answer @fluffy.
Well it's not possible to change commit log.
So awk other tools way seems pretty hard in first place. BTW I did try awk method not the one you mentioned but some trick in my mind where I could collect all the fields as required from the commit message(which basically filters git log based on --author) but the problem comes when
There are cases when the "Reviewed By" is not present on the commit log's message body. That becomes a faulty case in the CSV/TSV. Is there a way I break up each single commit msg(all fields in it) and save in a list or something?

Comment: Basically what I am trying to do is 
```
1. Get git log.
2. search specific author's commits.
3. Extract some specific fields from it.
4. Save in some CVS/TSV based format(final goal is create an excel)
5. Import in an excel.
6. create some charts from it.
```
Just mentioning if there's a better and different and simple approach for this already well known.
May be I might have missed to convey something..

Comment: @fluffy one more way I could think of is.
If git saves the git log data somewhere on my local machine.
I could create a copy of it into a separate file(tempfile.txt) and change the keywords as mentioned, and then use the formatting commands where the (tempfile.txt) can be input.
How does that sound, is that possible to do ?

Comment: @SameeranJoshi I seem to have managed to implement an `awk` script that can handle both presence and absence of the trailer fields from your question. Please see the answer update for details. I didn't test it for all possible cases, but you get the idea and fix it when necessary. I probably might abuse the control characters in the implementation (they were not designed for this, of course), but it looks fine to me as of now. The only thing I'm really not sure about is how Excel supports TSV nowadays. I hope it does.

Comment: @SameeranJoshi I've just added a better `awk` implementation. Sadly, I'm not that good at `awk`, but hope it is now much better than the v1.

Comment: Thanks for pointers.
I have a basic working version which has helped us to gain better insights.
https://github.com/Sameeranjoshi/git-log-stats

Comment: @SameeranJoshi It's nice to have a feedback from you that a small script could inspire to create something better.