# Sed/Awk join odd and even lines - platform independent

Tags: linux, bash, awk, sed

hi all im trying to make this

```
2022-11-14 18:49:59             Indicator is < 3    
1       No
2022-11-14 18:49:59             Indicator is < 10   
1       No
2022-11-14 18:49:59             Indicator is < 22   
1       No
2022-11-14 18:49:59             Indicator is < 1    
1       No
```

into

```
2022-11-14 18:49:59             Indicator is < 3    1       No
2022-11-14 18:49:59             Indicator is < 10   1       No
2022-11-14 18:49:59             Indicator is < 22   1       No
2022-11-14 18:49:59             Indicator is < 1    1       No
```

i found that you can use `sed 's/something/some//2'` for every second encounter but how to make it for 1st, 3th, 5th,.... and so one

Comment: So you want to join all pairs of lines starting with the first and second? If yes `sed -n 'N;s/\n/\t/;p' file` should do the trick (with a tab to separate the two joined lines, replace `\t` by anything you want).

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7841607/how-can-i-combine-odd-and-even-numbered-lines) answer your question?

Comment: Or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9605232/how-to-merge-every-two-lines-into-one-from-the-command-line)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this with `awk` using modulo.

```
$ awk -v val=2 'NR % val == 0{print prev, $0} {prev = $0}' file
2022-11-14 18:49:59             Indicator is < 3     1       No
2022-11-14 18:49:59             Indicator is < 10    1       No
2022-11-14 18:49:59             Indicator is < 22    1       No
2022-11-14 18:49:59             Indicator is < 1     1       No
```

It looks at the record number `NR` and calculates modulo 2 of it. Since every second line comes out as 0 it will then print the previous *prev* and the current `$0` line.

Remarks:

- Printing last odd lines is undefined, the given example is clear. It can even be seen as a feature to not print them (even out a data set).
- This keeps execution time in mind and is a fast approach.

Comment: Thank you
Do you have time to explain what is this between ' '?

Answer (score 2):

```
$ awk '{printf "%s%s", $0, (NR%2 ? OFS : ORS)}' file
2022-11-14 18:49:59             Indicator is < 3     1       No
2022-11-14 18:49:59             Indicator is < 10    1       No
2022-11-14 18:49:59             Indicator is < 22    1       No
2022-11-14 18:49:59             Indicator is < 1     1       No
```

The minor differences between this and [@AndreWildberg's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74642842/1745001) are:

1. This holds no lines in memory while Andres holds 1 line (not an issue, just a difference).
2. If there were an odd number of lines in the input, this would print
   all of them (though with a blank instead of a terminating newline at the end of the last line) while Andres would delete the last line (but produce a terminating newline), e.g.:

```
$ seq 5 | awk '{printf "%s%s", $0, (NR%2 ? OFS : ORS)}'
1 2
3 4
5 $
```

vs

```
$ seq 5 | awk 'NR % 2 == 0{print prev, $0} {prev = $0}'
1 2
3 4
$
```

Comment: Also, this elegantly scales to different modulo values, where Andre's answer is basically hard-coded to 2. (It could be fixed, but then this is essentially the fix.)

Answer (score 2):

Another approach

```
$ paste - - <file

2022-11-14 18:49:59             Indicator is < 3        1       No
2022-11-14 18:49:59             Indicator is < 10       1       No
2022-11-14 18:49:59             Indicator is < 22       1       No
2022-11-14 18:49:59             Indicator is < 1        1       No
```

or (more fragile)

```
$ pr -w112 -2at file

2022-11-14 18:49:59             Indicator is < 3        1       No
2022-11-14 18:49:59             Indicator is < 10       1       No
2022-11-14 18:49:59             Indicator is < 22       1       No
2022-11-14 18:49:59             Indicator is < 1        1       No
```

Comment: You can use `pr -2ats' '` (the `-s` option turns off line truncation, so no need to calculate page width)